# Suppose $m \leq n$ and define $b_{m+1} = b_{m+2} = \cdots = b_n =0$ What if $m = n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, definition

I was studying linear algebra with Friedberg Linear Algebra fourth edition, printed in 2002, and reading the section 1.2 Vector Spaces, at the example 4 (page 10) it says:
Let $$f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots a_1x + a_0 $$ and $$g(x) = b_mx^m + b_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots b_1x + b_0  $$ be polynomials with coefficients from a field $F$. Suppose that $ m \leq n $ and define  $b_{m+1} = b_{m+2} = \cdots = b_n =0 $. Then $g(x)$ can be written as $$ g(x) = b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0.$$

It does this, so it would be possible to define the sum of two polynomials as: $$f(x)+g(x)= (a_n+b_n)x^n+(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})x^{n-1} + \cdots + (a_1+b_1)x + (a_0+b_0)$$

I grasp that this works fine if $m<n$, informally, is just "placeholders" of zeros in order to two polynomials have the same degree. But if the polynomials are already of the same degree there is no meaning to do this because you could sum them normally. And if we follow this definition in this case ($m=n$) we set $b_{n} = 0 = b_{m}.$
I thought this could be a possible error, but checking  [the web of errata for the book](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/linalg/errata1.html) it is not listed. So perhaps my interpretation of the definition is wrong, what do you think? 1) it should be $m<n$ in the definition? or 2) the sequence  $b_{m+1} = b_{m+2} = \cdots = b_n =0$ does not modify $b_{m}$ when $m=n$?

I'm inclined to the latter, but is still confuse to me because if $m=n$ then $b_{n} = b_{m} = 0.$

Comment: It is not an error. It is just a clumsy way of writing. If $m=n$ you should do nothing.

Comment: @markvs Yes, I just realized that, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I understand it this way: $b_{m+1}=b_{m+2}=\cdots=b_n=0$ really means $$\forall k\in\Big(\mathbb N\cap(m,n]\,\Big),\quad b_k=0.$$ In the case $m=n$, this is saying nothing (because $(n,n]$ is the empty set). In particular, it's not saying $b_n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $f(x) = a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ and $g(x) = b_1x+b_0$.

Then, to simplify the notation, you write $g(x) = b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0$ where $b_3=b_2=0$. You define this new coefficients to be able to write things like
$f(x)+g(x) = (a_3+b_3)x^3+(a_2+b_2)x^2+(a_1+b_1)x+(a_0+b_0)$.

If $m$ happens to be equal to $n$, there's no need of new coefficients for $g$, which reflects in the fact that there's no integers in the range $m+1, m+2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: Yes, I realized this until I finish the question, and now I cannot decide if this is clumsy or elegant, hehe.

Comment: In many occasions in Mathematics is considered more elegant to state this kind of things without specifying what happens in the extreme cases, and in most of the cases an adequate interpretation gives the right result.